# Trying to measure friction of RC car tire

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I'm trying to figure out a way to measure the friction coefficient between my cars tire and the surface its driving on. My current idea is to drive the car into a wall at a constant speed and figure out the current usage from the battery. What equations would I need to use to make it work this way?

Comment: This would measure the rolling resistance, not the friction between the tires and the ground. You could imagine the car would require much more current usage with the brake on, despite changing absolutely nothing about the physical interface between rubber and road.

Comment: You can measure the pulling force that the car generates as a function of wheel rpm. A simple spring balance will probably do.

Comment: Why not use any one of the many existing tables freely available online that give the coefficients for rubber on concrete or other surfaces?

Comment: Or do the tilt test, if you can measure the angles very well, since you can tilt wheels in the way so that they wont roll while you tilt

Comment: The easiest way is to sacrifice a tire and cut a strip to attach to a block of known mass and drag horizontally on your surface with a spring balance. If your careful, you might be able to distinguish between the static and kinetic coefficients of friction.

Comment: Instead of sacrificing a tire, you could ask the manufacturer for some samples to test. Tell them you are a student.

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of friction - static and kinetic. Kinetic friction is the force that holds the tire back as it is dragged along the road in a skid. Static friction is the force that holds a stationary tire to the road, preventing a skid. This is the friction as you normally drive, because the bottom of the tire is stops as it meets the road.

These two forces are different. You have to pull harder to break a tire loose and start a skid than you need to keep a skid going.

In both cases, the force of friction is proportional to the vertical force holding the tire to the road.

$$F_{static} = \mu_{static} N$$

$$F_{kinetic} = \mu_{kinetic} N$$

To calculate either $\mu$, you need to measure the force of friction and the force holding the tire to the road.

It takes a lot more force to skid a tire when it is held down by the weight of a car than it does when you have a loose tire. So the first step might be to take a tire off the car. If you do, $N$ is the weight of the tire.

Then measure the force needed to start the tire skidding to get $\mu_{static}$. And measure the force needed to keep it skidding to get $\mu_{kinetic}$.

---

I just noticed that this is an RC car. So you won't need to take the tires off.

Another way would be to drive it at a constant speed, which you would have to measure. Then steer it in a circular path. You would have to measure the radius.

$$F_{centripetal} = m v^2/r$$

Given the weight of the car, you could then find $\mu_{static}$.

Comment: It has come to my attention that I am trying to find the rolling resistance and not the actual coefficients of friction. This changes my question a bit as I am now wondering how I can relate the current output of the RC cars battery to find the torque generated at the cars axle.